# windows git shows difference for whole file

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, git-config, core.autocrlf

as i am using below setup for my work station 
windows, intellij idea

till now everything was working fine with changes in intellij and was able to see difference using `git diff`
command. 
 but suddenly now even if i am making single line change in .java file it shows whole file in `git diff` command

also i checked my intellij which shows `CRLF` on right bottom corner.

and in my c:/users/umeshuser/.gitconfig  which is as below

```
[user]
    email = umesh.g@xyz.com
    name = UmeshGoti
[core]
    autocrlf = true
    safecrlf = false
```

and below is config file available in my root project/.git/config

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://{bitbucketURL}/backend-api.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "API_PROD"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/API_PROD
[branch "API_DEV"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/API_DEV
```

i have tried by uninstalling git and intellij then also issue is not resolved

can someone please help me to solve this issue

please note just before 2-3 days i think updated windows OS. so, is there any issue with that also

also intellij diff tool shows me below formats CR and CRLF
[image]

please advice me to resolve this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you checked if the line endings are differents ? Try to run `git diff` with `--ignore-cr-at-eol` argument (and also  `--ignore-all-space` if you want to ignore space/tabs conversion)

Comment: @jhamon Thanks for your quick reply
just tried using your way but still it doesn't make any effect. can you please check if by other i can resolve

Comment: Could it be the file encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select the correct line ending from bottom right panel of the intellij

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLtOp.png

Comment: Thanks @furkanbegen
but when i do LF from CRLF and entire project is shown as diff in git status command
can you please help for this

Comment: can you try with git config --global core.autocrlf true